# www.*.us.com not being indexed, but *.us.com is on Google Webmasters

Tags: subdomain, search-engine-indexing, no-www

I've read the FAQ and searched the help center. My URL is `http://www.etechsupport.us.com`.

I have also done 301 redirect of `no-www` to `www`.

But `www` is not being indexed by Google and `no-www` is. My SEO guy wants with `www`.

I researched and found my URL is subdomain to `us.com` domain but my site is unique.

I want all pages to be indexed as `www` and not as `no-www`.

What is the best option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not waited enough time for Google to apply the URL changes. As you can see [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3aetechsupport.us.com) your site is indexed however the changes are not reflecting yet.... changing URL names can take months, Google will most likely be aware of your changes but is waiting to see if the change is intended. So there's nothing more you have to do other than wait. The important thing is site visitors are not effected.

Comment: Thanks @bybe. But my question is why Google treats etechsupport.us.com as SubDomain? Most of the options are disabled in GWT with the message "Restricted to top level domains only".

Comment: Add the site with www. in GWT.

Comment: @Ojal: That's because it _is_ a subdomain of [us.com](http://us.com), which is owned by the company that sells the subdomains, CentralNic Ltd. It's not a [top-level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), although it looks confusingly like one. The actual ccTLD for the United States is just [.us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us).

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: Thanks. The problem was resolved using HTTP 301 redirects of etechsupport.us.com to www.etechsupport.us.com